# Catching exception, raising custom exception that ends with sys.exit

Tags: python

I want to catch an exception, raise a custom exception, and then sys.exit(0) to exit the program gracefully.

I have tried the following:

In my main execution code, I have this:

```
try:
  (some code)
except Exception as ex:
  raise CustomException
```

and in CustomException class:

```
class CustomException(Exception):  
    def __init__(self):
        sys.exit(0)
```

Unfortunately my custom exception is not getting raised this way and the main Exception is not getting caught.

I understand I could `raise SystemExit` but I need to generate a custom exception for me to catch in another code block down the road.

Comment: Do you want to raise SystemExit (and exit the program) *or* raise CustomException (and handle it). Currently you do the former during preparation of the latter.

Comment: Do you mean you will have some more code elsewhere which has ‘except CustomException: sys.exit(0)’ ?

Comment: I realize I now I can't raise a Custom Exception AND exit the program. I plan on having another code block elsewhere to specifically catch my CustomException as "except CustomException: sys.exit(0)"